# Windows developer command prompt says I'm not administrator when I am

Tags: windows

[image]So I started the Developer command prompt in windows, and ran it as an administrator by right-clicking and choosing 'run as administrator.' It says Administrator: Developer command prompt right up there at the top. But when I ran an `sn` command. Windows responded `Failed to read [file] because Administrator permissions are needed...` I have a screenshot attached. Is there something else I need to do besides run the command prompt as an administrator?

Comment: Thanks ManoDestra for correcting my typo!

Answer (score 2):

I see what I did. I was doing `sn` on a directory instead of a file. When I did it on the file it worked just fine.

Comment: So the real issue is simply a misleading error message? Thanks Microsoft.